# Print using Foxit in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pdf, printing, foxit

I am trying to get a PowerShell script to work to print out multiple documents to the default printer. Any ideas on what I can do to get this to work?

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.pdf"
foreach ($file in $files) {
    "c:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe" /t $file
}
```

Comment: If foxit reader is associated with `.pdf` files `Start-Process -FilePath $file –Verb Print` should do

Comment: Yeah that works but it doesn't work when running in a script while there is no active users logged in. My ultimate goal is to have a script run to print out files .

Answer (score 2):

Use the parameter `/p` for printing to the default printer, use the [call operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) (`&`) for executing command paths in quotes.

Change this line:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe" /t $file
```

into this:

```
& "c:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe" /p $file
```